# Error code 1410 when calling RegisterClass() on the second time

Tags: winapi

This is the first time calling Sleep_Detection() which is a function that includes RegisterClass():

```
//some codes here...
Execute_Command(0);
Sleep_Detection();  **//First time calling, no problem**
```

---

This is the second time calling Sleep_Detection() but it's now calling from inside of the SleepDetectionProc() callback function, the error occurred here.
I used GetLastError() and here I got an error code of 1410 which means "ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS".

```
LRESULT _stdcall SleepDetectionProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    {
        if (wParam == PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND)
        {
            cout << "System restored" << endl;
            Execute_Command(0);
            Sleep_Detection();  **//Second time calling, error code 1410**
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

---

This is the Sleep_Detection() function:

```
void Sleep_Detection(void)
{
    WNDCLASS WindowClass = { 0 };
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = SleepDetectionProc;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = (L"Sleep detection");

    if (!GetClassInfo(WindowClass.hInstance, WindowClass.lpszClassName, &WindowClass))
    {
        if (!RegisterClass(&WindowClass))
        {
            cout << "Cannot register class (Error Code: " << GetLastError() << ")" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            cout << "registered" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Class already exists" << endl;

    HWND WinHandle = NULL;
    if (!FindWindow(WindowClass.lpszClassName, ConsoleTitle))
    {
        if ((WinHandle = CreateWindow(L"Sleep detection", L"", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)) == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Cannot create window (Error Code: " << GetLastError() << ")" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            cout << "window created" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Window already exists" << endl;

    int upRes;
    MSG Message;

    while (upRes = GetMessage(&Message, WinHandle, 0, 0))
    {
        if (upRes == -1)
        {
            cout << "An error occurred when getting window messages (Error Code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Got Message!" << endl;
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
        }
    }
}
```

---

So I basically called Sleep_Detection() twice and it also called the RegisterClass() function inside. I guess the error could be related to overwritten the RegisterClass()?

Comment: 'So I basically called Sleep_Detection() twice and it also called the RegisterClass() function inside'.. and you got 'ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS'.  Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I guess you're not *really* into win32 development? Well, to make it "work" just ignore this error, and it'll be fine.

Comment: @valdo Yeah I'm not very familiar with it but I'm trying to, do you have a fix?I don't wanna just leave it there cuz it seems like a little problem but I just don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Sounds like you've taken some code you found online and used it without any serious effort to understand it. Because the system is telling you what is wrong. You should reflect a little on having received an error message and completely ignored it. Why did you do that? Why do you think that the developers of this library provided error codes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan plz don't get me wrong, I was on MSDN for the last several hours just trying to figure out the best way to fix it and I'm absolutely not ignoring it. It says the class already exists, should I unregister the class and destroy the window every time before I'm planning on calling them for the next time?

Comment: I'd read the code first. Note the part where it attempts to detect whether or not the class is already registered and so avoid doing so again. Why is that not working as intended? Secondly, why design the code this way. Why not register the class once at startup? Why is your message loop non-standard? What happens if messages are sent to other windows? Have you considered debugging? Do you understand how to do so? Do you understand the code at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> WNDCLASS WindowClass = { 0 };
> WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = SleepDetectionProc;
> WindowClass.lpszClassName = (L"Sleep detection");
> ```

`WindowClass.hInstance` is zero, which will cause `GetClassInfo()` to fail even if the window class already exists, because the value of `NULL` for the parameter `hInstance` is reserved for classes defined by the system, which is stated at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633578(v=vs.85).aspx):

> *hInstance*
>
> A handle to the instance of the application that created the class. To
>   retrieve information about classes defined by the system (such as
>   buttons or list boxes), set this parameter to **NULL**.

So `RegisterClass` will always be attempted, which of course fails on the 2nd try.

To correct the error, initialize `WindowClass.hInstance` like this:

```
WindowClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);  // get hInstance of current process
```

If the code is called from a DLL, replace `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` with the handle of that DLL. By the way, [`HMODULE` is interchangeable with `HINSTANCE`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903), that is the base address of the module.

Comment: When I do WNDCLASS WindowClass = { 0 }; to initialize the members of the structure, I was not even thinking about hInstance. Still need to know more details about GetModuleHandle as well. The code works, thank you!